# SDK Manager doesn't open in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, eclipse-adt

I have a problem that I can't solve.  This is a picture about my problem :

[image]

How can I solve these errors??????????

Comment: just move on to android studio already

Comment: the error is showing path not found so have you checked if the specified path is correct or not?

Comment: I don't know what is "Path" , so where or how can I see The "Path" ???????